# When can we say that a sequence is bigger or smaller than another sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let's say there are two sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$. I often see the inequality
$$\{a_n\} > \{b_n\}.$$
I don't understand how can we make such comparison to determine if a sequence is bigger or smaller than another one.

Comment: I *don't* see such an inequality often, and probably never without a prior definition of $>$ for sequences.

Comment: Ti's probably meant to be $a_n>b_n$, for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: If you're seeing this in calculus then it's probably meant to be $a_n>b_n$ for all $n$, or for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: This thus of course depend on your book/lecturer. Several things are possible: $a_n > b_n$ for every $n$, or more likely for all but finitely many $n$, or, if both sequences converge it could mean $\lim a > \lim b$. It could also mean the image of a is greater in cardinality as the image of b.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is a line in my book it says the following:
If sequences {a <sub>n</sub>} and {b <sub>n</sub>} converge respectively at a and b and p <sub>1</sub> exists from N such that for every n $\gt$ p <sub>1</sub> and n ∈ N, so the condition {a <sub>n</sub>} $\leq$ {b <sub>n</sub>} then, $\lim_{n \to infty}$ {a <sub>n</sub> $\leq$ $\lim_{n \to infty}$ {b <sub>n</sub>} or the same could be a $\leq$ b.
Sorry for the bad formatting, new to Stack, not really sure why it's not being shown correctly.

Comment: @halrankard "all sufficiently large n" is something I thought about but not sure of how the books would interpret it.

Comment: Formally, I mean that there is some $n_0$ such that $a_n\geq b_n$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which is the same as what is in the answer you accepted.

Comment: By the way, math formatting on this network is via LaTeX and MathJax, rather than html. See this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. If you click the "edit" button on any of the answers in the network you can see how it's written in code. (Just make sure to click cancel so you don't submit edits accidentally.)

Comment: I can translate what you wrote: "If sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converge respectively at $a$ and $b$ and $p_1$ exists from $\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>p_1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so the condition $\{a_n\}\leq \{b_n\}$ then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{a_n\} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \{b_n\}$ or the same could be $a\leq b$." I can't quite parse what this is saying (is it really word for word from your book?) but the reference to $p_1$ makes me think we're talking about "sufficiently large $n$" aka "all but finitely many $n$" here.

Comment: @halrankard "...so the condition {}≤{} is met, then..." my mistake there. But, yeah I pretty much understand it now. Although the book I am working with is a bit complicated and not so easy to grasp I would appreciate any books you might like on Math Analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we will talk about endless sequences, and than $\{a_n\}$ will be bigger than $\{b_n\}$ if and only if, there is only finite number of $n$'s s.t
$$b_n>a_n$$
If you insists to talk about finite sequences so I think its fair to say that we relate only to the coincide numbers, there exists in both.

Comment: Let's say a1 = 0  and b1 = 1, but then for all n, a ≥ b. Does n = 1 break the inequality?

Comment: My mistake. Edited the answer

Comment: So that would make my example as I said above valid. Got it!!!